# Lollypop music player not working

Tags: 20.04

I just installed the Lollypop music palyer from its repository `ppa:gnumdk/lollypop` but was not able to launch it. I tried launching it from CLI but it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lollypop", line 14, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

I tried `sudo apt insatll python3-gi` but it shows as already installed.

EDIT: Also tried `sudo apt-get install -y python-gobject` but to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure that Python installation is not messed up on your system? What is the output of `which python`, `which python2` and `which python3`?

Comment: Can't assure that. I had a problem with my bluetooth not working and i thought it was an issue with python 3.7 so i tried some things then. Fixed it with switching off secured boot. Currently i have python 3.8.6

Comment: `which pyhton` does not return anything, `which pyhton2` returns `/usr/bin/python2` and `which python3` returns `/usr/local/bin/python3`

Comment: So you have wrong python3 installation. Remove it from `/usr/local/bin/python3` and retry. And do not touch it next time. It is essential system component.

Comment: Please give more specific instructions. I'm a newbie.

Comment: Will this work? First I remove python3 using `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/python3`, then build it again using `$ ./configure --prefix=/usr`
`$ make`
`$ sudo make install`

Comment: Do not touch system-wide python3! Installing to `/usr` will increase the mess in the system. Use venv for experiments.

Comment: Did some things again and now all three return `usr/bin/python` , `usr/bin/python2` , `usr/bin/python3` respectively. And, python is connected to python2.

Answer (score 2):

For 20.04 LTS you do not need any PPA. This package is already available in the *universe* [pocket](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lollypop).

Install the package using commands below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lollypop
```

As you already have the PPA added - remove it with:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnumdk/lollypop
```

Comment: Removed Lollypop. Removed PPA. Universe was already added. Reinstalled Lollypop. Still same issue.

Comment: Btw, I have already tried building it from the source files following the instructions in the README file.